# Some doubts in a JUnit test Spring example

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

I am studying the Spring Core certification and I have the following doubt related to the **Junit** use in Spring.

I have an example that give me the following **RewardNetworkTests** class

```
package rewards;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;

import common.money.MonetaryAmount;

/**
 * A system test that verifies the components of the RewardNetwork application
 * work together to reward for dining successfully. Uses Spring to bootstrap the
 * application for use in a test environment.
 */

public class RewardNetworkTests {

    /**
     * The object being tested.
     */
    private RewardNetwork rewardNetwork;

    /**
     * Need this to enable clean shutdown at the end of the application
     */
    private AbstractApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Create the test configuration for the application from one file
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                TestInfrastructureConfig.class);
        // Get the bean to use to invoke the application
        rewardNetwork = context.getBean(RewardNetwork.class);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // simulate the Spring bean destruction lifecycle:
        if (context != null)
            context.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRewardForDining() {
        // create a new dining of 100.00 charged to credit card
        // '1234123412341234' by merchant '123457890' as test input
        Dining dining = Dining.createDining("100.00", "1234123412341234",
                "1234567890");

        // call the 'rewardNetwork' to test its rewardAccountFor(Dining) method
        RewardConfirmation confirmation = rewardNetwork
                .rewardAccountFor(dining);

        // assert the expected reward confirmation results
        assertNotNull(confirmation);
        assertNotNull(confirmation.getConfirmationNumber());

        // assert an account contribution was made
        AccountContribution contribution = confirmation
                .getAccountContribution();
        assertNotNull(contribution);

        // the contribution account number should be '123456789'
        assertEquals("123456789", contribution.getAccountNumber());

        // the total contribution amount should be 8.00 (8% of 100.00)
        assertEquals(MonetaryAmount.valueOf("8.00"), contribution.getAmount());

        // the total contribution amount should have been split into 2
        // distributions
        assertEquals(2, contribution.getDistributions().size());

        // each distribution should be 4.00 (as both have a 50% allocation)
        assertEquals(MonetaryAmount.valueOf("4.00"), contribution
                .getDistribution("Annabelle").getAmount());
        assertEquals(MonetaryAmount.valueOf("4.00"), contribution
                .getDistribution("Corgan").getAmount());
    }
}
```

So this test class contains the **setUp()** method that create the context starting from the **TestInfrastructureConfig.class** configuration class:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Create the test configuration for the application from one file
    context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            TestInfrastructureConfig.class);
    // Get the bean to use to invoke the application
    rewardNetwork = context.getBean(RewardNetwork.class);
}
```

This is the content of the **TestInfrastructureConfig.class** configuration class:

package rewards;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import config.RewardsConfig;

```
@Configuration
@Import({
    TestInfrastructureDevConfig.class,
    TestInfrastructureProductionConfig.class,
    RewardsConfig.class })
public class TestInfrastructureConfig {

    public LoggingBeanPostProcessor loggingBean(){
        return new LoggingBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

So on the tutorial it say to me that if I delete the **setUp()** method and after doing it I try to execute my test I will obtain a red bar **because the rewardNetwork field is null**

Ok, I think that it could depend by the fact that deleting the **setUp()** method I am not obtaining the context from the **TestInfrastructureConfig.class** configuration class that in turn **import** the **RewardsConfig.class** configuration class in which the **component scanning** is declared by the use of:

```
@ComponentScan("rewards")
```

So the appliaction can't use the **RewardNetworkImpl** class (that implement the **RewardNetwork** interface) declared into a subpackage of the **rewards** package and that it is **annoted as @Service**:

```
@Service("rewardNetwork")
public class RewardNetworkImpl implements RewardNetwork {
    ...................................
    ...................................
    ...................................
}
```

Ok, I think that this is clear (or am I missing something?)

My doubt is. Coming back to the previous **test method**:

```
@Test
public void testRewardForDining() {
    // create a new dining of 100.00 charged to credit card
    // '1234123412341234' by merchant '123457890' as test input
    Dining dining = Dining.createDining("100.00", "1234123412341234",
            "1234567890");

    // call the 'rewardNetwork' to test its rewardAccountFor(Dining) method
    RewardConfirmation confirmation = rewardNetwork
            .rewardAccountFor(dining);

    ...................................................
    ...................................................
    ...................................................
}
```

As seen an exception is thrown when the **rewardAccountFor()** method is called on the not founded **rewardNetwork** object but why, using the debugger, the **createDining()** method is called on the **Dinning dinning** object?

Why this object is instantiated without no problem?

This is the **Dinning** class code:

```
public class Dining {

    private MonetaryAmount amount;

    private String creditCardNumber;

    private String merchantNumber;

    private SimpleDate date;

    /**
     * Creates a new dining, reflecting an amount that was charged to a card by a merchant on the date specified.
     * @param amount the total amount of the dining bill
     * @param creditCardNumber the number of the credit card used to pay for the dining bill
     * @param merchantNumber the merchant number of the restaurant where the dining occurred
     * @param date the date of the dining event
     */
    public Dining(MonetaryAmount amount, String creditCardNumber, String merchantNumber, SimpleDate date) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.creditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
        this.merchantNumber = merchantNumber;
        this.date = date;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new dining, reflecting an amount that was charged to a credit card by a merchant on today's date. A
     * convenient static factory method.
     * @param amount the total amount of the dining bill as a string
     * @param creditCardNumber the number of the credit card used to pay for the dining bill
     * @param merchantNumber the merchant number of the restaurant where the dining occurred
     * @return the dining event
     */
    public static Dining createDining(String amount, String creditCardNumber, String merchantNumber) {
        return new Dining(MonetaryAmount.valueOf(amount), creditCardNumber, merchantNumber, SimpleDate.today());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new dining, reflecting an amount that was charged to a credit card by a merchant on the date specified.
     * A convenient static factory method.
     * @param amount the total amount of the dining bill as a string
     * @param creditCardNumber the number of the credit card used to pay for the dining bill
     * @param merchantNumber the merchant number of the restaurant where the dining occurred
     * @param month the month of the dining event
     * @param day the day of the dining event
     * @param year the year of the dining event
     * @return the dining event
     */
    public static Dining createDining(String amount, String creditCardNumber, String merchantNumber, int month,
            int day, int year) {
        return new Dining(MonetaryAmount.valueOf(amount), creditCardNumber, merchantNumber, new SimpleDate(month, day,
                year));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the amount of this dining--the total amount of the bill that was charged to the credit card.
     */
    public MonetaryAmount getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of the credit card used to pay for this dining. For this dining to be eligible for reward,
     * this credit card number should be associated with a valid account in the reward network.
     */
    public String getCreditCardNumber() {
        return creditCardNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the merchant number of the restaurant where this dining occurred. For this dining to be eligible for
     * reward, this merchant number should be associated with a valid restaurant in the reward network.
     */
    public String getMerchantNumber() {
        return merchantNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the date this dining occurred on.
     */
    public SimpleDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Dining)) {
            return false;
        }
        Dining other = (Dining) o;
        // value objects are equal if their attributes are equal
        return amount.equals(other.amount) && creditCardNumber.equals(other.creditCardNumber)
                && merchantNumber.equals(other.merchantNumber) && date.equals(other.date);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return amount.hashCode() + creditCardNumber.hashCode() + merchantNumber.hashCode() + date.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Dining of " + amount + " charged to '" + creditCardNumber + "' by '" + merchantNumber + "' on " + date;
    }
}
```

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dining` seems to be a class and `createDining` seems like a `static` method. No `Dining` object needs to be created to invoke such a method.

This is equivalent to doing

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Spring isn't involved in `static` method invocations.

Comment: yes, Dining is a class and createDining() is a static object definied into this class. So are you say to me that, using Spring, I can access to a static method of a class also if I have no configured this class as bean?

Comment: @AndreaNobili This has nothing to do with Spring. You're invoking a `static` method. The invocation doesn't need an instance.